# MYSQL Create table with Unique values

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to UPDATE my table from another table.  I would like to ignore duplicates and also delete any matches in that table.

```
Source Table          Table 1              Table 2
Customer | Address    Customer | Address   Customer | Address
__________________    __________________   __________________

Mike      123 Main    Mike      123 Main     Bob      999 1st 
Steve     456 Maple   Steve     456 Maple
John      789 Elm     John      789 Elm
Bob       999 1st
```

For example, Table 2 will only have the unique entry after "Source Table" is compared to Table 1.  I am using MYSQL/PHP.

Any direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it matter which table has the unique value(s)?

Comment: if table 2 was empty, then you can't update. update cannot produce new records. you'd have to INSERT the bob record.

Comment: @ethrbunny Yes, Table 2 should have the Unique value.  Table 2 is ultimately the table used in conjunction with a ticketing system (To avoid duplicate tickets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2a506/1)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Source
    (`Customer` varchar(5), `Address` varchar(9))
;

INSERT INTO Source
    (`Customer`, `Address`)
VALUES
    ('Mike', '123 Main'),
    ('Steve', '456 Maple'),
    ('John', '789 Elm'),
    ('Bob', '999 1st'),
    ('Bob', '999 1st')
;

CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`Customer` varchar(5), `Address` varchar(9))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`Customer`, `Address`)
VALUES
    ('Mike', '123 Main'),
    ('Steve', '456 Maple'),
    ('John', '789 Elm')
;

CREATE TABLE Table2
    (`Customer` varchar(5), `Address` varchar(9))
;

DELETE FROM Table2;
INSERT INTO Table2
    (`Customer`, `Address`)
SELECT DISTINCT Customer, Address
FROM Source
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table1 WHERE Source.Customer = Table1.Customer)
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2a506/1/0)**:

```
| CUSTOMER | ADDRESS |
|----------|---------|
|      Bob | 999 1st |
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  That makes perfect sense and was exactly what I was looking for.